# Stale data shown in react component

Tags: reactjs

I have just started learning react, and am working on a POC. However, I am facing a weird issue.

I have two components, Perfumes and PerfumeSearchResults. Perfumes is the component which is re-using PerfumeSearchResults in a loop.

Below is the code:

```
class Perfumes extends React.Component{
  render(){
return(
            <div>
                <div>Perfumes Page</div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.perfumeName} onChange={this.handleChange}/>                    
                </div>
                <div>{
                    this.state.filteredPerfumes.map(function(perfume){
                        return <div>{perfume.perfumeName} <PerfumeSearchResults value={perfume}/></div>
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class PerfumeSearchResults extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props); 

        this.perfume = props.value;

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <span>{this.perfume.perfumeName}</span>
                <span>{this.perfume.perfumeId}</span>
                <span>{this.perfume.house}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is, when I am filtering the results, I am getting correct data in {perfume.perfumeName}. However, the child component is showing me a different data all together.

Like, if perfume array is [Cool Water, Polo Blue, Polo Black], when I type black, perfume.perfumeName shows polo black, but perfumeSearchResult component is showing me Cool water.

I am not sure what I am missing here. Since the constructor is defined I am assuming that after every modification, PerfumeSearchResult components would be destructed and reconstructed with relevant data being passed to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructor will be called only once. So if the props gets changed, `this.perfume` will not get updated. You don't need to assign props to anything, you just use them in your component.

```
class PerfumeSearchResults extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <span>{this.props.value.perfumeName}</span>
                <span>{this.props.value.perfumeId}</span>
                <span>{this.props.value.house}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This works too, thanks. I added a console.log to the constructor, and saw that they are being called multiple times. However, the order was odd. When array had 5 elements, the constructor was called 5 times. When I filter, and array has 3 items, constructor is not called. However, when I delete the search strings, the constructor is called 3 times. Maybe it's due to some delay.

Answer (score 1):

```
    this.perfume = props.value;
```

should be like this.

```
this.perfume = this.props.value;
```

(You are missing this.)

and you can try

```
render(){
      this.perfume = this.props.value;
return(
        <div>
            <span>{this.perfume.perfumeName}</span>
            <span>{this.perfume.perfumeId}</span>
            <span>{this.perfume.house}</span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Inside the constructor, since props is passed as an argument, we should be able to access it directly without using this. Moving the code to render did work, thank you :)